# Set behave unexpectedly: local, or not local?

Tags: c++, set, local-variables

I have encountered a problem when I am using *set* in C++. I write the same program in both C++ and Python.
Here are the codes:
C++ ver.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <random>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

void func(int n, set<int> S)
{
    int i = rand() % n;
    S.insert(i);
    printf("#S = %d\n", S.size());
}

void test()
{
    int n = 100;
    set<int> S;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        func(n, S);
    }
    printf("final:\n");
    printf("#S = %d\n", S.size());
}

int main()
{
    test();
    return 0;

}
```

Python ver.

```
import random

def func(n, S):
    i = random.randint(0, n)
    S.add(i)
    print("#S = {:d}".format(len(S)))
    pass

def test():
    n = 100
    S = set()
    for i in range(10):
        func(n, S)
        pass
    print("final:")
    print("#S = {:d}".format(len(S)))
    pass

def main():
    test()
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pass
```

Here are the outputs:
C++ ver.

```
#S = 1
#S = 1
#S = 1
#S = 1
#S = 1
#S = 1
#S = 1
#S = 1
#S = 1
#S = 1
final:
#S = 0
```

Python ver.

```
#S = 1
#S = 2
#S = 3
#S = 4
#S = 5
#S = 6
#S = 7
#S = 8
#S = 9
#S = 10
final:
#S = 10
```

I am confused. Isn't set *S* exterior to *func()* in the C++ ver.? Why does it not change? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter `S` of `func()` is passed by value, it's copied from the argument, any modification on it inside `func()` has nothing to do with the argument (i.e. `S` in `test()`).

You should make it pass-by-reference. Then given `func(n, S);` the parameter `S` of `func()` and `S` in `test()` would refer to the same object.

```
void func(int n, set<int>& S)
//                       ^
{
    int i = rand() % n;
    S.insert(i);
    printf("#S = %d\n", S.size());
}
```